# Update/Insert MySQL values with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to both update and insert new database entries in my SQL database. The database runs through XAMPP because we wanted to test out if we could make it work using an external server.

I got the following code:

```
MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=");
MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO projectDatabase.lesson (name, classRoom, TeacherID, active) VALUES ('"+ lessonName +"', '"+ className +"', '"+ UserData[0] +"', 1)", sqlcon);
MySqlDataAdapter mda2 = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM projectDatabase.lesson WHERE TeacherID = "+ UserData[0] +" AND active = 1", sqlcon);

sqlcon.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
mda2.Fill(ds, "lesson");
DataRow dr = ds.Tables["lesson"].Rows[0];
sqlcon.Close();
```

After this patch of code, the selected database items get inserted into arrays just fine, but there is no sign of an entry being added to the database.

The select works fine, but the insert (and update too for that matter) won't execute or even produce errors. I have been looking around for answers, but they all drastically change the way we have done the database queries so far. Is there a way to make it work using my current code?

Comment: Where are you executing the first DataAdapter?

Comment: On a button click named btnStartCanvas inside a try event.

Comment: Add the code where you actually use the first DataAdapter.

Comment: Ahh i see where i went wrong now. I was under the impression that the MySqlDataAdapter was parsing its content straight to the database, but i actually still need to use a method to actually parse the statement. It seemed so obvious that after the select statement, that i have to put its results into a dataset, but i did not think that it would be required for the insert statement.